# how to change only size of normal text, not headers with EM

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and I'm using em for font size, but in body, `font-size: 1.2em;` changes the size of my headers too. how can I stop this?

I tried

```
h1, h2, h3 {
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

but that brings them to the size of the normal text.

Comment: Can you make an example in JsFiddle or CodePen?

Comment: @PauloFernando sure! https://codepen.io/burrito-with-a-hat/pen/NWERKeM

Comment: `font-size: inherit` means it will have the same font-size as the parent element, if you don't want this, why just not use font-size inherit?

Comment: You could use `rem` for headline font sizes, and keep the font size on the root element fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `:not()` pseudo-class. [Can I use `:not()`?](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Anot()) shows 93.74% browser support.

```css
body :not(h1, h2, h3, p.default) {font-size: 1.2em}
```

```html
<h1>Primary heading</h1>
<p>The default text size is 16 pixels</p>

<h2>Secondary heading</h2>
<p>With a 1.2 multiplier, this text is expected to be 19.2px (unless the browser default settings have been modified or zoom is applied.)<p>

<h3>Tertiery heading</h3>
<p>With the default settings, `h1` is 2em (32px), `h2` is 1.5em (24px) and `h3` is 1.17em (18.72px).</p>

<p class="default">This text inside `p.default` is the default size</p>
```